# RenderRoutes with PrivateRoute

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am trying to implement PrivateRoute in ReactJS , App.js using `renderRoutes` and `lazy` loading. However, cannot figure out the syntax. Can someone help:

```
  const App = () => {
  return (
    <StoreProvider store={store}>
          <Router history={history}>
            {renderRoutes(routes)}
          </Router>
    </StoreProvider>
  );
};
```

in the routes.js i am trying to protect the Customers route:

```
const routes = [
  {
    path: '/auth',
    component: AuthLayout,
    routes: [
      {
        path: '/auth/login',
        exact: true,
        component: lazy(() => import('views/Login'))
      },
    ]
  },
  {
    route: '*',
    component: DashboardLayout,
    routes: [
      {
        {
          path: '/customers',
          exact: true,
          component: lazy(() => import('views/CustomerManagement')) <--- PrivateRoute
       }
    ]
  }
];

export default routes;
```

and the PrivateRoute.js is

```
  export const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => (
        <Route {...rest} render={props => (
            localStorage.getItem('user')
                ? <Component {...props} />
                : <Redirect to={{ pathname: '/login', state: { from: props.location } }} />
        )}
        />
    )
```

Comment: Does https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/auth-workflow help?

Comment: sorry not exactly sure how the example is relevant

Comment: If you are trying to **protect** some routes (not accessible unless authenticated, and hence redirect the user to some **public** route i.e. login etc), you can follow that example. That example is about "Public", "Private" route and "Auth" flow. Aren't you trying to do the same?